# C++ - function reads the same line twice when trying to ignore it

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have to create a convoluted program to read 3 values from a file, calculate the average, and output it to a file, all using different functions, and the function that gets the input from a file needs to be called 3 times separately with no fancy stuff. I'm incrementing a variable by 1 each time and input is taken and skipping lines accordingly.  It seems to get the first 2 inputs fine when using ignore() until the newline character, but when using it twice to skip the first 2 inputs and get the third, it seems to be getting the second input again and using that to calculate the average. For example I got the average of 5,7 and 10 as 6.3~ when it should be 7.3~.
Am I doing something wrong by using ignore until the newline character twice? I've included the code from my main and the two relevant functions.

```
int main() {

    double input_1, input_2, input_3;
    double average;
    int count = 1;

    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    infile.open("infile.txt");
    outfile.open("outfile.txt");

    input_1 = get_input(infile, count);
    count = count+1;

    input_2 = get_input(infile, count);
    count=count+1;

    input_3 = get_input(infile, count);

    average = calculate_avg(input_1, input_2, input_3);

    output_to_file(average, outfile);

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
double get_input(ifstream& infile,  int number) {

    double input_value;

    if (number == 1) {
        infile >> input_value;
    }
    else if (number == 2)
    {
        infile.ignore (100, '\n');
        infile >> input_value;
    }
    else if (number == 3)
    {
        infile.ignore (100, '\n');
        infile.ignore (100, '\n');
        infile >> input_value;
    }
    return input_value;
}
```

---

```
double calculate_avg(double val_1, double val_2, double val_3){
    double avg;

    avg = (val_1 + val_2 + val_3)/3;

    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Please don't put TABs in your code samples here! Edited this time ...

Answer (score 2):

`std::fstream::ignore` will extract and discard characters from the input stream, so 100 won't be the best choice

Use following in `get_input()` for sake of *"no fancy stuff"*

```
infile.seekg(0); // rewind
if (number == 1) {
    infile >> input_value;
}
else if (number == 2)
{
    infile >> input_value;
    infile >> input_value;
}
else if (number == 3)
{
    infile >> input_value;
    infile >> input_value;
    infile >> input_value;
}
return input_value; //only the last read value
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I hadn't realized it would only return the last read value, I thought it would cause some kind of error. I guess I should test stuff out more.

Answer (score 1):

write function get_input as:

```
double get_input(ifstream& infile,  int number) {
    double input_value;
    infile >> input_value;
    infile.ignore (1, '\n');
    return input_value;
}
```

the will work because you opened file and then reads it consequentially, so after you read number - internal pointer is at \n symbol, and you do not have to skip several lines, you need just to skip `\n` symbol